# On inserting date into a table i get: Duplicate column name

Tags: python, sql

I'm inserting data into a table where i'm skipping, excluding, data that is already in the table with that price and sku value.

Im running in an issue where when my variables have the same value ex. `price` and `sale_price` are both 0 or `companiy_id` and `status` are both 1 i get an error Duplicate column name.

```py
sql_insert = "INSERT INTO apps_scraper_data_history (sku, price, company_id, date_time, status, item_key, price_sale) SELECT * FROM (SELECT %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT sku FROM apps_scraper_data_history WHERE price=%s AND sku=%s)"
val_insert = (sku, price, company, date, status, key, sale_price, price_scrape, sku)
cursor.execute(sql_insert, val_insert)
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning every details in the question. It would be even great if you mention the dbms also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't define column names for alias `tmp`. So that, when value of two columns are same those might be conflicting. Please try below query with column aliases.

```
sql_insert = "INSERT INTO apps_scraper_data_history (sku, price, company_id, date_time, status, item_key, price_sale) SELECT * FROM (SELECT %s sku, %s price, %s company_id, %s date_time, %s status, %s item_key, %s price_sale) AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT sku FROM apps_scraper_data_history WHERE price=%s AND sku=%s)"
val_insert = (sku, price, company, date, status, key, sale_price, price_scrape, sku)
cursor.execute(sql_insert, val_insert)
```